# Filling in Web Forms with Speech Recognition

Tags: javascript, html, speech-recognition, visual-studio-lightswitch

When using Windows Speech Recognition or Dragon NaturallySpeaking in LightSwitch HTML 5 Client Forms, the webpage behaves as if nothing had been entered even though all required fields have been filled in using speech recognition.

I presume because no actual key is pressed the system is unaware that the text boxes have been filled in.

Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: have you tried creating each item as a dataItem first, then when you are about to save, assign the dataItem values to the Table data.

Comment: I've tried using a local property and then assigning the value of the local property to the field but it is showing as undefined in JavaScript even though it has been filled in.  If I say press 1 instead of just dictation then it works but that's only okay if I want to enter the number 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found that adding the following code in the post render event 
for all input text fields has fixed the problem by forcing the change event when the element loses focus otherwise the change event never fires:

```
    $(element).focusout(function (e) {
       //Force the change event to occur so that speech recognition works
       $(e.target).change();
    })
```